# How to make a dot product in a vector of matrices in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have

```
a = np.ones((10, 4, 3))
b = np.ones((10, 3, 5))
```

and I want

```
c = np.dot(a, b, axis=0)
assert c.shape == (10, 4, 5)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: ........ `a@b`?

Comment: @Divakar what if the same length axis is not 0? still works?

Comment: Would you please provide an example of the kind of values you wish to produce, or is that unimportant in the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, there are 10 matrices in `a` of shape *4 x 3* and 10 in `b` of shape *3 x 5*, and you wish to (matrix-)multiply corresponding matrices in the two sets.

As already mentioned, `np.matmul(a, b)` or `a @ b` achieves this purpose. If the operation is unclear, however, it is interesting to look at an explicit way of achieving what you want using `np.einsum`, which explicitly specifies indices as in mathematics:

```
np.einsum('ijl,ilk->ijk', a, b)
```

In the string in the *first argument*, left-hand side specifies the indices of the input matrices and the right-hand side the output indices. Read the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to understand it better.

Just to check that the results are the same:

```
>>> np.allclose(np.einsum('ijl,ilk->ijk', a, b), a @ b)

True
```

But `einsum` takes some more time, so for such simple usages, it's wise to resort to `@`:

```
>>> %timeit np.einsum('ijl,ilk->ijk', a, b)
    %timeit a @ b

14.2 µs ± 176 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2.73 µs ± 22.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`c = np.matmul(a, b)` is probably what you are looking for. It produces the shape you need.

But this does not mean it is the kind of calculation you want to be executed. I would look into the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) in order to be sure.